# sum values from datagridview loop

Tags: loops, datagridview

I have a simple question, there are two datagridviews, in one of them is

```
               id Dealer code Sales 
               1  aaaa   121    1
               2  bbbb   131    1 
               3  aaaa   121    1
               4  aaaa   121    1
               5  bbbb   131    1
```

in second datagridview:

```
              id Dealer Code Sales
              1   aaaa   121
              2   bbbb   131
```

I am Updating Sales column by clicking to the row and updating row by row.

```
    Dim a = (From row In DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)() Where   Convert.ToString(row.Cells(2).Value).Equals(TargetsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells(9).Value.ToString) Select row).Count
    TargetsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells(6).Value = a
```

Question: is it possible to update it by pressing one button?

What I have tried:

```
        For i As Integer = 0 To TargetsDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim a = (From row In DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)() Where Convert.ToString(row.Cells(1).Value).Equals(TargetsDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString) Select row).Count
        TargetsDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value = a
    Next
```

but it not working, need yours help. Thanks.